# VisualStudio: How to add the dotted border to a UserControl at design time?

Tags: visual-studio, user-controls

i have a user control that descends from UserControl.

When dropped onto the form the user control is invisible, because it doesn't have any kind of border to show itself.

The PictureBox and Panel controls, at design time, draws a dashed 1px border to make it visible.

What is the proper way to do that? Is there an attribute you can use to make VS add that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no property that will do this automatically. However you can archive this by overriding the OnPaint in your control and manually drawing the rectangle.

Inside the overridden event you can call base.OnPaint(e) to draw the controls content and then add use the graphics object to paint the dotted line around the edge.

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (this.DesignMode)
             ControlPaint.DrawBorder( e.Graphics,this.ClientRectangle,Color.Gray,ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed);   
    }
```

As you can see you will need to wrap this extra code in an if statement that queries the controls DesignMode property so it only draws in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The way that `Panel` does this (which suggests that this is the actual proper way of doing this) is with the [`DesignerAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). This attribute can be used for design time additions to `Control`-components as well as non-control components (like `Timer`).

When using the `DesignerAttribute` you need to specify a class derived from `IDesigner`. For a `Control` designer specifically, you should derive from [`ControlDesigner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your particular implementation of `ControlDesigner` you want to override the [`OnPaintAdornment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.onpaintadornments(v=vs.110).aspx). The purpose of this method is specifically drawing designer hints on top of the control, like a border for example.

Below is the implementation that `Panel` uses. You could copy that and use it for your control, but you obviously need to adjust the parts that specifically refer to the `Panel` class.

```
internal class PanelDesigner : ScrollableControlDesigner
{
    protected Pen BorderPen
    {
        get
        {
            Color color = ((double)this.Control.BackColor.GetBrightness() < 0.5) ? ControlPaint.Light(this.Control.BackColor) : ControlPaint.Dark(this.Control.BackColor);
            return new Pen(color)
            {
                DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash
            };
        }
    }
    public PanelDesigner()
    {
        base.AutoResizeHandles = true;
    }
    protected virtual void DrawBorder(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)base.Component;
        if (panel == null || !panel.Visible)
        {
            return;
        }
        Pen borderPen = this.BorderPen;
        Rectangle clientRectangle = this.Control.ClientRectangle;
        int num = clientRectangle.Width;
        clientRectangle.Width = num - 1;
        num = clientRectangle.Height;
        clientRectangle.Height = num - 1;
        graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen, clientRectangle);
        borderPen.Dispose();
    }
    protected override void OnPaintAdornments(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)base.Component;
        if (panel.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
        {
            this.DrawBorder(pe.Graphics);
        }
        base.OnPaintAdornments(pe);
    }
}
```

`ScrollableControlDesigner` is a public class that you may or may not want to use as a base for your particular designer implementation.

Comment: +1. This is the correct way to draw design time adornments. Instead of checking the DesignMode property, it's better to create a custom designer.